# Transaction Failed but showing as Pending on Etherscan

Tags: ether, metamask, wallets, coinbase

So I just started using ether after the same was legalized in my country (India). I use Coinbase Wallet for my Storage of ether. I decided to shift to Metamask from Coinbase Wallet and as such initiated a transfer of my Ether, I selected Max Option for the same and then initiated the transfer. The transaction has been pending for hours now. I checked with Coinbase Wallet and on the app it shows as Transaction Failed. But on etherscan it shows as Pending.
So, the transaction happened at transaction hash : https://etherscan.io/tx/0x689281c886374982946117efa52e43835b9b8d3e0915ec3d8871b4a37b894ca3

I got scared of the same (understandably so!). So, I used my metamask to send some ether to the Coin Base Wallet in case of gas issues but it seems that is not happening as well. Those transactions are also stuck as pending. So, all of my ether is currently stuck as pending. Please advice on what I can do! Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: So, it seems by the time I posted this my transaction was "Dropped". Not sure what that means though. Currently, I have 2 more pending transactions for deposits in the coinbase wallet that I did which still show up as pending. Not sure if they are going to be dropped as well.

Conclusion: Don't use Max Feature as it may cause some ether whether it's just 0.0001 ETH short it will cause you a lot of confusion till the time the transaction drops or fails (not sure if they are the same thing!!)

Comment: When sending a transaction I'd check ethgasstation.info and etherscan.io/gasTracker for the recommended gas value. These last days the network has been pretty busy and gas required for quick minting was quite high. Transactions with low gas price usually remain as pending until their are replaced or dropped if network remains congested for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the way to replace the transactions that were pending by adjusting the nonce. I did spend some more money on it though. I have also shifted from the Coinbase Wallet as it doesn't allow to adjust Gas and Nonce which I think are a absolute must if you don't want transactions to become stuck in a loop for days at end.